# Oracle Forms developer 11gR2, not showing all the records

Tags: forms, oracle, image-processing

I have created a table to preserve employee information with PP photos.
I used ORACLE database and Forms Developer, both 11gR2.
I created a **`table (ID > number, image > blob and other fields`**, i will include the script below), populated with few sample records, created a folder in **`y:\images\`**, copied jpg images there.
Forms : displayed all the items (all default options), a trigger with the image item.
problem : when i run the form, everything (DML) looks working fine but it does not show the sample records that I previously inserted using script. Those records still exist, I checked. I couldn't figure out why it is happening. Can you please give me any clue of what I should do. The codes are given below.

---

1 create table.

```
DROP TABLE emp2 PURGE ;
CREATE TABLE emp2 (
empno       NUMBER(2),
ename       VARCHAR2(20),
emp_photo   BLOB );
```

2 insert some sample data.

```
INSERT INTO emp2 VALUES (1, 'Rahim', EMPTY_BLOB()) ;
INSERT INTO emp2 VALUES (2, 'Karim', EMPTY_BLOB()) ;
INSERT INTO emp2 VALUES (3, 'Shafiq', EMPTY_BLOB()) ;
INSERT INTO emp2 VALUES (4, 'John', EMPTY_BLOB()) ;
INSERT INTO emp2 VALUES (5, 'Robin', EMPTY_BLOB()) ;
```

3 copy jpg images in y:\images\ folder.

4 create forms with all the above columns.

5 Trigger when image pressed :

---

```
DECLARE
    v_loc   VARCHAR2(30) := 'y:\images\' ;
BEGIN
    READ_IMAGE_FILE(v_loc||:emp2.empno||'.jpg','JPEG', 'emp2.emp_photo');
END ;
```

---

Thank you in advance.

Murshed Khan

Comment: Hi, I am sorry I did a silly mistake.

Comment: I did not commit in the script, so it did not save and it was not showing in the forms. I have wasted 4/5 hours today to find what happened. I am sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

Complete it using a commit, It should work